# How to create an interactive console interface using node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am creating an console interface,in which the program ask some questions and user answers it through console,there are questions where the user must only enter limited no of inputs,i found some ways to get console input in `node js` but cant find a way to limit users inputs and ask questions one after another, after asking questions want to create a `JSON` object from it.
for eg,i will ask questions like:

- What is your name?
- List 3 of your hobbies ?
- Enter a desired username ?

After asking this questions i will construct a `json` object like

```
    {"name":"codebean","hobbies":['Exploring','Coding','Trucking'],"username":'codebean'}
```

Difficulties that i face are :

- How to ask questions one after other, ie, serially
- Limit the user inputs to a particular count
- Terminate the program after entering the final question's answer

I only have little experience with `NodeJs` and what i was able to establish was nothing but rubbish,and here is what i established

```js
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
var input = [];
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  console.log('What is your name');
  var name = process.stdin.read();
  if ((name !== null) && (name !== '/n')) {
    input.push(name.split('/n')[0]);
    console.log(input);
  }
  console.log('List 3 of your hobbies ?');
  var hobbies = process.stdin.read();
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
  console.log(input);
});
```

Comment: Personally, having made CLIs and stuff in NodeJS, I would use a library for this sort of thing.  Using the stdio streams is a bit messy when working with prompts.

Comment: You can search [npm](http://npmjs.com/) for one you like, but a popular one like [`prompt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt) might do.

Comment: Prompt seems nice but i am suppose to do it in the native way ? any help ??

Comment: For a fancier text-based interface you could have a look at [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed).

Comment: Blessed seems to be nice,thanks for the info

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Having made CLI applications in NodeJS, I would recommend using a library like [`prompt`](http://npmjs.org/prompt) to better organize your code.  A library would keep it more readable than what you can do naively (in my opinion).

However, if you want some native alternative, you could use Node's [`EventEmitter` object](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to make things look a bit more organized, opposed to handling it all inside of the stdin callback:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var prompt = new EventEmitter();
var current = null;
var result = {};
process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.on('data', function(data){
  prompt.emit(current, data.toString().trim());
});

prompt.on(':new', function(name, question){
  current = name;
  console.log(question);
  process.stdout.write('> ');
});

prompt.on(':end', function(){
  console.log('\n', result);
  process.stdin.pause();
});

prompt.emit(':new', 'name', 'What is your name?');

prompt.on('name', function(data){
  result.name = data;
  prompt.emit(':new', 'hobbies', 'What are your hobbies?');
});

prompt.on('hobbies', function(data){
  result.hobbies = data.split(/,\s?/);
  prompt.emit(':new', 'username', 'What is your username?');
});

prompt.on('username', function(data){
  result.username = data;
  prompt.emit(':end');
});
```

This code uses some sort of a *state-tracking method* (I wouldn't know if there is an actual term).

Basically, there is a variable that keeps track of what you programming is looking for, in our case that is `current`.  This variable is also used to trigger our `prompt` EventEmitter whenever data is received.

Inside events we can change the `current` variable to ask for something else (I made a shorthand `:new` event to do this), manipulate the data however we please, and also add it input our `result` variable.

If you want to "tag" your input (a little marker at the beginning), you can do that simply with `stdin.write`:

```
prompt.on(':new', function(){
  // ...
  process.stdin.write('> ');
});
```

Here is what that code looks like in action:

```
$ node ...
What is your name?
> Jamen Marzonie
What are your hobbies?
> programming, philosophy, petting cats
What is your username?
> jamen

 { name: 'Jamen Marzonie',
  hobbies: [ 'programming', 'philosophy', 'petting cats' ],
  username: 'jamen' }
```

Comment: @CodeBean, hope this helps.  Remember you can accept answers by clicking the green check-mark.  Feel free to ask me questions if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your time , it really helps !

Answer (score 1):

I routinely use coroutines for this case, which yield questions and consume answers. Co-routines are generators which consume values to yield the next result. In our case they consume the user's responses, and yield prompts.

This makes for supremely readable and debuggable sequences of prompts and simple state management.

Note the use of `function*` in the example code which runs in node 14. This syntax defines a coroutine in javascript.

The first two 'library' functions in the example code at the end expose node's native stdio capabilities so that you can write 'stateful' coroutines such as...

```
function* createSimpleSequence(print) {
  print("Welcome to the game");
  let playerName = "";
  while(!playerName){
    playerName = yield "What is your name? ";
  }
  print(`Hello, ${playerName}`);
  yield "Press enter to restart the game";
}
```

Note that there is no explicit state management, as the co-routine allows us to 'pick up where we left off' after yielding a question, and we can use while loops and other apparently synchronous control flow primitives to decide how and when to 'progress' between states.

The full example requested by the original poster would look like...

```
function* createOriginalPostersSequence(print) {
  let name = "";
  while (!name) {
    name = yield "What is your name?";
    if (!name) {
      print("Your name cannot be empty");
    }
  }

  let hobbyString = "";
  while (!hobbyString) {
    hobbyString = yield "List three of your hobbies, separated by ','";
    const hobbyCount = hobbyString.split(",").length;
    if (hobbyCount !== 3) {
      if (hobbyCount === 0) {
        print("Your hobbies cannot be empty");
      } else if (hobbyCount == 1) {
        print("What! Do you really only have one hobby, think again!");
      } else if (hobbyCount == 2) {
        print("Two is better than one, but I asked for three!");
      }
      hobbyString = "";
    }
  }
  const hobbies = hobbyString.split(",").map((hobby) => hobby.trim());

  let username = "";
  while (!username) {
    username = yield "What is your username?";
    if (!username) {
      print("Your username cannot be empty!");
    }
    if (!username.match(/[a-z_]+/)) {
      print(
        "Your username can only contain lowercase letters and underscores."
      );
      username = "";
    }
  }
  const data = {
    name,
    hobbies,
    username,
  };
  print(`Your full data is ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}
```

Finally this is the full source code which would run both the simple sequence, and then the original poster's requested interactive prompt sequence interactively in Node 14.

```
// core 'library' exposing native node console capabilities for co-routines

function getAnswer() {
  process.stdin.resume();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    process.stdin.once("data", function (data) {
      resolve(data.toString().trim());
    });
  });
}

async function runSequence(sequenceFactory, clearScreen = true) {
  function print(msg, end = "\n") {
    process.stdout.write(msg + end);
  }
  let answer = undefined;
  const sequence = sequenceFactory(print);
  while (true) {
    const { value: question } = sequence.next(answer);
    if (question) {
      print(question, " : ");
      answer = await getAnswer();
      if (clearScreen) {
        console.clear();
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

// examples using the library

function* createSimpleSequence(print) {
  print("Welcome to the game");
  let playerName = "";
  while (!playerName) {
    playerName = yield "What is your name? ";
  }
  print(`Hello, ${playerName}`);
  yield "Press enter to restart the game";
}

function* createOriginalPostersSequence(print) {
  let name = "";
  while (!name) {
    name = yield "What is your name?";
    if (!name) {
      print("Your name cannot be empty");
    }
  }

  let hobbyString = "";
  while (!hobbyString) {
    hobbyString = yield "List three of your hobbies, separated by ','";
    const hobbyCount = hobbyString.split(",").length;
    if (hobbyCount !== 3) {
      if (hobbyCount === 0) {
        print("Your hobbies cannot be empty");
      } else if (hobbyCount == 1) {
        print("What! Do you really only have one hobby, think again!");
      } else if (hobbyCount == 2) {
        print("Two is better than one, but I asked for three!");
      }
      hobbyString = "";
    }
  }
  const hobbies = hobbyString.split(",").map((hobby) => hobby.trim());

  let username = "";
  while (!username) {
    username = yield "What is your username?";
    if (!username) {
      print("Your username cannot be empty!");
    }
    if (!username.match(/[a-z_]+/)) {
      print(
        "Your username can only contain lowercase letters and underscores."
      );
      username = "";
    }
  }
  const data = {
    name,
    hobbies,
    username,
  };
  print(`Your full data is ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}

// demo to run examples

async function run() {
  await runSequence(createSimpleSequence);
  await runSequence(createOriginalPostersSequence);
  process.exit(0);
}

run();
```

Comment: This is great!!

Comment: Shouldn't `print` use `stdout` rather than `stdin`...?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I will swap for `stdout` in the line which currently reads `process.stdin.write(msg + end);` Maybe it worked previously owing to echo behaviour in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it natively in Node 18.

```
const readline = require('node:readline/promises');  // Requires Node 18

async function main() {
    // Create interface
    const rl = readline.createInterface({input:process.stdin, output:process.stdout});

    // Ask questions
    const name = await rl.question("What is your name? ");
    rl.write("Enter three hobbies:\n");
    const hobby1 = await rl.question("  Hobby #1: ");
    const hobby2 = await rl.question("  Hobby #2: ");
    const hobby3 = await rl.question("  Hobby #3: ");
    const username = await rl.question("What username would you like? ");

    // Close interface
    rl.close();

    return {name, username, hobbies:[hobby1, hobby2, hobby3]};
}

main();
```